# There is an error "cannot create .moc/main.moc ", when I compile the mysql driver for Qt5.7

Tags: c++, gcc, qt5

Environment: Ubuntu 16.04 + Qt 5.7 + MySql 5.7

As the title, on the time I compile the mysql driver for Qt5.7, I execute make command after I qmake and this error appears:

> /home/cc/ProgramFiles/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/bin/moc -DQT_NO_MTDEV
>   -DQT_NO_LIBUDEV -DQT_NO_TSLIB -DQT_NO_LIBINPUT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/home/cc/ProgramFiles/Qt5.7.0/5.7/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I/home/cc/ProgramFiles/Qt5.7.0/5.7/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql
>   -I/usr/include/mysql -I/home/cc/ProgramFiles/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtSql/5.7.0 -I/home/cc/ProgramFiles/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtSql/5.7.0/QtSql -I/home/cc/ProgramFiles/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore/5.7.0 -I/home/cc/ProgramFiles/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore/5.7.0/QtCore -I/home/cc/ProgramFiles/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include -I/home/cc/ProgramFiles/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtSql -I/home/cc/ProgramFiles/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I/usr/include/c++/5 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5 -I/usr/include/c++/5/backward -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include main.cpp -o .moc/main.moc moc: Cannot create .moc/main.moc Makefile:652: recipe
>   for target '.moc/main.moc' failed make: *** [.moc/main.moc] Error 1

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: do you have permission to create that file wherever the compiler's trying to drop it?

Comment: maybe, i attempt to use qt creator tocompile the driver,  but also a error appear:     error: Cannot write file/mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_plugin_qsqlmysql.pri: Cannot create parent directory, i don't konw why...

Comment: thank you ,I  understand  the error reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar and this worked for me. It rebuilt the driver.

```
cd /home/[user]/Qt/5.7/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql

sudo /home/[user]/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/bin/qmake “INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/include/mysql” “LIBS+=-L/usr/lib/mysql” mysql.pro

sudo make

sudo cp /home/[user]/Qt/5.7/Src/qtbase/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers

sudo cp /home/[user]/Qt/5.7/Src/qtbase/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so /home/[user]/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers

sudo cp /home/[user]/Qt/5.7/Src/qtbase/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so /home/[user]/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/sqldrivers
```